# How to use success & failure block in SDwebimage

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7, sdwebimage

I have latest version of `SDWebimage` but it doesnt have Success & failure
I tried the following method but `SDwebimage` doesnt have method

```
[self.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageURL]
              placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourPlaceholder.png"]
                       success:^(UIImage *image) {
                           // remove animation

                       }
                       failure:^(NSError *error) {
                           NSLog(@"thumbnail error: %@",error);
                           // handle failed download

                       }];
```

Does anybody know how to add success & failure block in `SDwebimage` `setImageWithURL` or any other alternatife
I want to handle if there is some error  while getting image from URL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
[self.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourPlaceholder.png"]
                          completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                              //... completion code here ...
                          }];
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution for Swift 3 :

```
cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: url) { (image, error, cache, urls) in
            if (error != nil) {
                //Failure code here
                cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "ico_placeholder")
            } else {
                //Success code here
                cell.imageView.image = image
            }
}
```

Solution for Objective C :

```
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:url
                  placeholderImage:nil
                         completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                                if (error) {
                                  //Failure code here
                                  self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ico_placeholder"];
                                } else {
                                  //Success code here
                                  self.imageView.image = image;
                                }
}];
```

Hope you guys find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
            imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString), completed: {
                (image, error, cacheType, url) in
                // do your custom logic here
            })
```

sample code for swift 2.0

Answer (score 0):

it has completion block

```
completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
```

You can check if error is nil, then everything is fine.

Comment: Yeah thats what i am doing now